# Cannot access a closed Stream. Error throwing

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, itext

Cannot access a closed Stream. Error throwing

[image: Cannot access a closed Stream. Error throwing]

How to resolve?

Comment: What is `createPDF` implementation, please?

Comment: html1 = "<div style='background-color:green'>AKHILESH</div>";
            //byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(html);
            MemoryStream ms = createPDF(html1);
            //write to file
            string path =Server.MapPath("~/Repositery Data/abc.pdf");
            FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            ms.WriteTo(file);
            file.Close();
            ms.Close();

Comment: Could you, please, edit the question: 1. Move the code from link into question's body; 2. Add `createPDF` implementation to the question.

Comment: Read (and *embrace!*): [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As you tagged the question with [tag:itext], [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427872/1729265) might solve your issue. If it does, your question would be a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because something that opens things in memory, e.g streamreader, `StreamReader` closes the underlying stream automatically when being disposed of. The using statement does this automatically.

However, the `StreamWriter` is still trying to work on the stream (also, the using statement for the writer is now trying to dispose of the `StreamWriter`, which is then trying to close the stream).

The best way to fix this is: don't use `using` and don't dispose of the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. See this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862261/can-you-keep-a-streamreader-from-disposing-the-underlying-stream)