# Cannot access a closed Stream. When using PDFReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, itext

I have this file, which is a Stream:

```
 var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["id"].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

Now I am trying to use PdfReader and PdfStamper to set Fields like so:

```
MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream();

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(streamFile);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile);
AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

fields.SetField("Full_Names", "JIMMMMMMAYYYYY");

pdfStamper.Close();
pdfReader.Close();
```

But when I try to do this, I get this error:

> Cannot access a closed Stream.

On this line:

```
pdfReader.Close();
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

I tried this, still getting the same error:

```
using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
{

    var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(streamFile))
    {
        using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile))
        {

            AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
            fields.SetField("Full_Names", "JIMMMMMMAYYYYY");

        }
    }

    outFile.Position = 0;

    await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(outFile);

}
```

UPDATE

I have tried converting the Stream to bytes like so:

```
var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = streamFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(ms.ToArray()))
                {
                    using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms))
                    {

                        AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
                        fields.SetField("Full_Names", "JIMMMMMMAYYYYY");

                    }
                }

                await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(ms);

            }
```

Same result...Cannot access a closed Stream on this line:

```
await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(ms);
```

The PutAsync is expecting a Stream as well

So when I do this:

```
var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(streamFile);
```

It uploads the file no problem. So I do believe the problem is trying to edit the PDF with iTextSharp.

Comment: Where is the error now? If it's on `outFile.Position = 0;` then you can just remove that line.

Comment: Its on this line. await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(outFile);

Comment: OK So you're using the `outFile` stream after it's closed. I would try moving those two lines inside the `PdfStamper` using block, or creating a new stream to re-read the output file.

Comment: To prevent iText from closing your stream, try to read all bytes from that stream into a `byte[]` and initialize the `PdfReader` from that `byte[]`.

Comment: @mkl How would I do that?

Comment: @mkl I tried convert the stream to the byte array, still does not work....iTextSharp is breaking everything.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427872/1729265) please.

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: I tried it, I dont get the error anymore, but my new PDF is still broken.

Comment: Nonetheless, in your latest code you use the memory stream first for copying the original stream and then as target of the pdf stamped. Thus, you likely have two files in that stream eventually... use separate memory streams or clear the single stream in-between.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to create the document in memory and add WaterMark after creation of document, but without saving a physical file as an intermediate step (which works as well but not nearly as neat).

```
public byte[] AsArray(List<DocumentData> list)
{
    MemoryStream streamIn = new MemoryStream(); // Set the initial stream for the document
    MemoryStream streamOut = new MemoryStream(); // Set the result output stream
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(streamIn); // create the writer for document

    CreateDocument(writer, list); // Method where the document actually get's made

    // Now the tricky bit
    // Translate the `streamIn` (that now contains the document stream) into a PdfReader
    // use the byte[] from streamIn to create a new MemoryStream()
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(streamIn.ToArray()));
    writer = new PdfWriter(streamOut); // Set the writer stream to be the streamOut

    SetWaterMark(reader, writer); // Method to read through the document and add watermarks

    return streamOut.ToArray();
}
```

and hey Presto, succes !

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

  byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

  try
  {
    PdfReader pdfReader = null;
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      int read;
      while ((read = streamFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
      }

      pdfReader = new PdfReader(ms.ToArray());

      pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms);


        AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
      fields.SetField("Full_Names", "JIMMMMMMAYYYYY");




      await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(ms);

    }
  }
  finally
  {
    if (pdfReader != null) pdfReader.Dispose();
    if (pdfStamper != null) pdfStamper.Dispose();
  }
```

Dispose the pdfReader and pdfStamper after the await is done.