# c# - iTextSharp - Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have been struggling with this issue for days now and cant find a solution anywhere, The only thing I can think of is that iTextSharp doesn't work....

First I create a MemoryStream like so:

```
MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream();
```

I have this Stream here:

```
var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

Which is a PDF file from Microsoft OneDrive

Then I take this Stream and assign it to iTextSharp's PdfReader like so:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(streamFile);
```

Then I use PDFStamper to make edits to the PDF File like so:

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile);
```

Then I do my edits like so:

```
AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("Full_Names", "JIMMMMMMAYYYYY");
```

Then I re-upload the file to OneDrive (which is also expecting a Stream) like so:

await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync(outFile);

But I get this error:

> Cannot access a closed Stream.

on this line:

```
await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(outFile);
```

When I just get my file from OneDrive and Upload it like so:

```
var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(streamFile);
```

It works! I am able to get the file and re-upload it, so its not an issue with the PDF file at all, iTextSharp is broken I have tried multiple things and nothing works at all. What is iTextSharp doing wrong? Here is my full code:

```
using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
{
    var streamFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(streamFile))
    {
         using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile))
         {
               AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
               fields.SetField("Full_Names", "JIMMMMMMAYYYYY");
         }
    }

    await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["item-id"].ItemWithPath("NewDocument-2.pdf").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(outFile);
}
```

What the hell is going wrong?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427872/1729265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stamper closes the inner stream when it gets disposed.  Add this line just below the line where you create the stamper:

```
pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
```

Comment: I tried it, I don't get the error anymore and my files gets uploaded, but the PDF is broken saying "Failed to load PDF document."

Comment: Try flushing the stream and setting its position to 0 after the stamper has been disposed, but before you use it.

Comment: @user979331 No problem!  Good luck to you!